# Liferay freemarker template - Using index in list

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, freemarker

I'm using Liferay 6.2 EE. I want to retrieve the index of my list elements within a freemarker Webcontent-Template by executing the following snippet:

```
 <#list cross_sellings_header.crossSellingsTile.getSiblings() as cross_selling>
         ${cross_selling?index}
         .... <#-- some implementation -->      
 </#list>
```

but i get an error message:

`Error on line 214, column 42, in template 20155#20195#ESHOP ARTIKEL
Found index, expecting one of:  chunk,  is_date,  is_hash,  float,  matches,  time,  number_to_datetime,  byte,  substring,  is_transform,  web_safe,  iso_ms_nz,  groups,  seq_contains,  iso,  is_method,  eval,  iso_ms,  iso_utc_m_nz,  parent,  capitalize,  number,  if_exists,  is_directive`

I also tried `index_of`but without success...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `?index` is deprecated, the correct syntax is:

```
${cross_selling_index}
```

Source:
[Freemarker list documentation](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_directive_list.html)

Comment: `?index` is not deprecated. It's `..._index` that's deprecated by `?index`. Apparently, said version of Liferay uses a too old FreeMarker version though.